# Node.src = variableName/adding HTML image with innerHTML and variable issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to incorporate some images "dynamically" by saving them as variables in an array and then editing the innerHtml of some divs to include them, but the images aren't showing. I'm using img.src = varName;   Here's a link to the code: https://repl.it/GBoa/1 (here's also a link to a website version where the images were uploaded: cardtestwdi.bitballoon.com). I would appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: Please include the code in the question instead of just linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `innerHTML` using a string, you will have to provide the full HTML string. You can't create a string and then use properties for regular DOM nodes. For example, you could use the following:

```
var imgElement = "<img src='" + myArray[i] + "' alt='test' width='200px' height='275px'/>";
```

However instead of doing this I would recommend creating the node in JavaScript using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and append it to the DOM using [`document.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.width = 200;
imgElement.height = 275;
imgElement.src = myArray[i];
myCard[i].appendChild(imgElement); // Append the image node to the card node
```

Comment: For HTMLImageElement, there is also the handy `Image(width, height)` constructor.